# El objeto 'float' no se puede interpretar como un entero(TypeError)

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, float, sintaxis

Python

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def funcion(x,y):
    ec = x + 2 * y
    return ec

h = float(input("tamaño de paso: "))
print()
s = float(input("¿Hasta que valor?"))
print()
n = (s / h) + 1
x = np.zeros(n)
y = np.zeros(n)
#x[0] = 1
#y[0] = 0.5
print(x[0],y[0])
for i in np.arange(1,n):
    y[i] = y[i-1] + (funcion(x[i-1],y[i-1]))*h
    x[i] = x[i-1] + h
    print()
    print(x[i],y[i])
plt.scatter(x,y)
```

Me salta un error

> File "C:\Users\ ... \PyCharmCE2020.2\scratches\modulo.py", line 496,
> in Metodo_de_Euler
> x = np.zeros(n) TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

¿Cómo lo reparo?
Explicarme el por qué, pls.

Comment: Según la [documentación de np.zero()](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.zeros.html), no puedes enviar un float como primer argumento. Y el resultado de `n = (s / h) + 1` es justamente un flotante. Para que siempre sea entero puedes cambiarlo a `n = int(s/h + 1)` o bien `n = s//h +1`

Comment: ¿Tal vez `n = int(math.ceil(s / h))`?